# Hit detection in flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, detection, hit

Hi i have a snake game that uses a timer to incremement the snakes size, and ive been trying to figure out hit detection on it. and have got to this stage

```
for (var i = 1; i < snake.length; i++){ //this is where I am trying to make the hit
                if (Math.floor(snake[0].x) == Math.floor(s.x) && Math.floor(snake[0].y) == Math.floor(s.y) ){
                    trace("hit");
                }
            }
```

is this how id go about it? thanks

Comment: try using hitarea  on the sprite containing the snake

Comment: How would i go about this, i just want it to hit detect the snake not the walls. any help and you would be a life saver

Comment: the same way as described below assuming your snake is made up of many joining sprites or MovieClips you should be hittesting on each one every enter frame

Comment: http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/as3hittesting/

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately i haven't got 2 objects that i can see to directly call a hit test on. Im trying to hit test part of an array with another part. As as soon as the game starts sprites are added to the array. Therefore i need to check the first sprite in the array with all other parts of the array. Here's my code http://ignitethatdesign.com/FlashLeaderBoard/Snake.as

Comment: In your fillGrid function you are creating sprites and drawing in them. Those are the sprites you need to do your hittestObject.

Comment: When you on create the sprites store a reference to them in an Array and test the Array in your testForHits function.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, I am telling you the simplest one.
When there are two sprites (or MoveiClips) you can check their hit by using

```
sprite1.hitTestObject( sprite2 );
```

This is the simplest way to achieve what you are looking for. So initially put four simple
sprites as walls and let snake crawl in between them and keep checking the "hitTestObject" on
the four walls. This way

```
this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler );

private function enterFrameHandler( e:Event ):void
{
     if( snake.hitTestObject( sprite1 ) ) { // do something }
     // repeat above if with all four walls
}
```

See here http://ashwani.50webs.com/snake.jpg

Comment: hey that will work for the walls thanks :) how would i go about doing a hit test on the snake itself? the snakes size is determined by an array btw

Comment: also with that code i get an error : 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

Comment: you need to import Event

import flash.events.Event;

Comment: Hi coderbanna how would i do a hit test on the snake itself? so like when the head hits its body it fires of a trace

Comment: hi dimension, your snake should be made up of some fix bone parts (some rectangle moviclip) and you need to check hit detection with each part to any other, if any part will hit other part, you got your snake dead. aight.